# Obtener uno de los campos de un archivo JSON a través de un formulario de consulta con PHP

Tags: php, html, json

Tengo un archivo `JSON` que posee para cada usuario 4 campos:

`[{"usuario":"1","nombre":"Pedro","dni":"10121015","fecha":"2019.01.01","pdf":"https://www.sitioweb.com/pdf/archivo.pdf"},{"usuario":"2","nombre":"María","dni":"20121015","fecha":"2019.02.01","pdf":"https://www.sitioweb.com/pdf/archivo2.pdf"}]`

Los campos son: *usuario*, *dni*, *fecha* y *pdf*

Quiero hacer un formulario con `html` y PHP que me permita buscar en el archivo `JSON` 2 de los campos y si éstos existen en el archivo `JSON`, entonces me devuelva el PDF asociado a esos dos campos

La búsqueda sería con el *DNI* y la fecha o con el *ID* de usuario más la fecha.

Se puede hacer ésto? - Alguien puede ayudarme?

NOTA: Lo primero que se me ocurre hacer es llamar con `PHP` el archivo `JSON` de la siguiente manera:

```
$data = file_get_contents("data/miarchivo.json");
```

Y luego convertir esa información en un array con la función json_decode().

```
$info = json_decode($data, true);
```

A partir de allí: ¿Cómo podría armar el formulario?
Voy bien encaminado?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Esto se puede hacer perfectamente. Ahora bien, no podemos hacer el trabajo por ti. ¿Ya investigaste cómo se crea el formulario y cómo se envían sus datos para ser comparados? ¿Cómo o donde vas a producir el JSON? ¿Cómo se recibe un JSON y se convierte a objeto legible en PHP? etc, etc. ¿Decidiste qué lógica vas a usar, cómo se van a relacionar los componentes del programa? ... Tienes que tomar la iniciativa, y preguntarnos cuando tengas dudas concretas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Si, he estado investigando un poco como hacerlo, pero no he podido dar con la forma adecuada. He agregado en la descripción de la consulta como se me ocurre transformar los datos del JSON en un array PHP. Pero no se todavía como construir la consulta del formulario para comparar los datos de éste array. Alguna orientación de cómo buscar ésta parte?

Comment: La primera decisión que tienes que tomar es ¿qué contexto voy a usar, qué herramientas, cómo voy a guardar los datos, etc? Generalmente esto se hace con bases de datos, desde el formulario envías unos datos, en el servidor lazas una consulta en base a esos datos y recibes una respuesta. Sin esa decisión inicial poco podemos ayudarte. Eso es básico para un punto de partida. Supongamos que dices, no, no me interesa guardar los datos en una base de datos... entonces tienes que decidir dónde los vas a guardar, si en un archivo JSON sin más o dónde. Se necesita partir de algo concreto, ¿me explico?

Comment: Si, entiendo perfectamente lo que me dices. Pensaba que no era necesario guardar los datos en una base de datos sinó que hacerlo directamente con PHP.

Comment: Tú puedes hacerlo como quieras, pero para este tipo de cosas lo que se suele usar es bases de datos, ten en cuenta que es más complicado buscar en un archivo directamente que en una base de datos, y mantener los datos, actualizar, comparar, salvaguardar... todo eso se complica si usas archivos. En una BD puedes guardar millones de registros y consultarlos con una rapidez increíble (claro, tienes que saber crear los índices y demás). [Mira este ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/6fju-td04/). Desde el formulario se manda un `id`  a la BD y trae los datos de esa persona.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo. De todos modos creo que estoy lejos de porder realizar lo que deso de ésta forma. En principio, sería exactamente lo contrario. Ingresar dos datos en un formulario HTML y a través de una búsqueda en el archivo JSON devuelva el PDF. Pensé que tal vez existía alguna manera de convertir el JSON en PHP para que la búsqueda por medio del formulario fuese más sencilla.

Comment: Te dije que también se puede hacer así. En PHP es muy fácil convertir un JSON a un objeto por ejemplo y luego recorrerlo, buscando en las claves los valores que quieras. Incluso para esto, si el JSON es pequeño, lo podrías hacer sin usar el servidor, guardando el JSON del lado del cliente. De todos modos, si vas a hacerlo en el servidor,  sería interesante aquí usar Ajax para mandar los datos desde el formulario al servidor y que éste te devuelva la respuesta de lo que encontró.